# How to get sub string of JSON string

Tags: json, json.net

I have got JSON output from a REST API, which has 15 key value pair objects.  I want to remove 8 key pair from this JSON and send this trimmed output further, 
and these key values pairs to be removed can be at any place within main JSON output and need not in a specific order.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var keysToRemove = new[] {"key1", "key2"}; // Add as many keys that you want to remove

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
{
    json.Remove(key);
}

var result = json.ToString();
```

Here, `json` is of the type `JObject` provided by the `Json.Net` library. You can use this object to parse, query and modify the underlying json.

[Example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)